# Abstract Base Class and public inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

I was hoping if any of you fine gents can help me to clarify something.

say I have the following code:

```
class someABC{
  virtual void foo() = 0;
}
```

and another class inheriting from it:

```
class inheritFromABS : public someABC
{
  inheritFromABS();
  void foo();
}
```

and another class that also inherits from someABC:

```
class alsoInheritFromABS : public someABC
{
  alsoInheritFromABS();
  void foo();
}
```

Now I have a list of objects of type someABC, so something like this:

```
  list<someABC *> myList;
  inheritFromABS *first = new inheritFromABS();
  alsoInheritFromABS *second = new alsoInheritFromABS();
  myList.push_back(first);
  myList.push_back(second);
```

I want to iterate through myList and call foo() on each. Is this even feasible? It compiles without errors or warnings, but in I get segmentation fault when I try to call foo().

Do I need to have list of objects of types inheritFromABS and alsoInheritFromABS in order to call foo(); for each?

EDIT: this is my actual code where it fails with segmentation fault:

```
llvm::Value *decafStmtList::Codegen() {
for(list<decafAST*>::iterator i = stmts.begin(); i != stmts.end(); i++)
{
    decafAST *tmp = *i;    
    tmp->Codegen();
}
return Constant::getNullValue(Type::getDoubleTy(getGlobalContext()));
}
```

So, the stmts contains one of the objects of type VariableExprAST and I want it to call codegen of the VariableExprAST, the code bellow:

```
llvm::Value *VariableExprAST::Codegen() {
    cout << "I am here" << endl;
    return 0;//FIXME: im broken
}
```

Everything complies without a single warning, but once I provide it a simple input, it fails with segfault right before tmp->Codegen();

Comment: What you describe should work, so you must have a problem elsewhere.

Comment: No this is very easy, and should work without any problems. If you **show us your code** we can tell you want is wrong with it.

Comment: you are putting objects in a list of pointers, you have pointers to someABC NOT "list of objects of type someABC"

Comment: You get a segfault? Do you have an error message, or a location in the source where it's occuring?

Comment: Actually, your code shouldn't even compile, or do you have a constructors that take pointers as arguments?

Comment: You should post some minimal code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thank you for fast replies ) sorry, this is just a simple example. I am trying to built a simple compiler with LLVM library. So, my actual code is a little bigger to post it here. But I believe that is the where the problem lays - i just throw some print statements before calling foo() of the object within the list and that is where it fails with segmentation fault.

Comment: @user1039063 Remember in C++ where it crashes is not necessarily a indication of where the bug is. C++ is a bit more difficult than that.

Comment: Posted code looks perfectly correct to me. I'm afraid your bug is elsewhere.

Comment: True, but I also throw a simple print method into my ABC, like void printMe() { cout << "I am indeed an abstract class" << endl; } and it prints the message without any problem. So, it makes me think that this is the problematic part. I'm gonna go over my code again, see if the bug could be elsewhere.

Comment: It looks like `stmts` is not in good shape when you arrive at `decafStmtList::Codegen()`, so trying to dereference `stmts.begin()` crashes. You have to look at what happens to `stmts` before arriving there.

Comment: Another possibility would be copying a `decafStmtList` object if class `decafStmtList` does not have valid copy constructors and/or assignment operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are attempting looks correct, but you need to store pointers in the list. It isn't clear how your current code would compile, but you probably mean to do this:

```
list<someABC *> myList;
inheritFromABS* first = new inheritFromABS();
alsoInheritFromABS* second = new alsoInheritFromABS();
myList.push_back(first);
myList.push_back(second);
```

i.e `inheritFromABS* first = ...` instead of `inheritFromABS first = ...`. You should also add a **virtual destructor** to your base class.

Here's a simple working example, following a classic theme. Note that in a real application you would use [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) instead of raw ones. This example is missing memory de-allocation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

struct Animal
{
  virtual void talk() const =0;
  virtual ~Animal() {}
};

struct Dog : Animal
{
  void talk() const { std::cout << "Woof woof!\n"; }
};

struct Cow : Animal
{
  void talk() const { std::cout << "Moooo!\n"; }
};

int main()
{
  std::list<Animal*> animals;
  animals.push_back(new Dog);
  animals.push_back(new Cow); 
  animals.push_back(new Dog);
  animals.push_back(new Cow);
  animals.push_back(new Dog);
  animals.push_back(new Cow);

  for (std::list<Animal*>::const_iterator it = animals.begin();
       it != animals.end();
       ++it)
  {
    (*it)->talk();
  }
}
```

Comment: @user1039063 This is what happens when you don't post your real code, you get a different question answered than the one you intended. Please post some real code.

Comment: @user1039063 when John says "real code", he means some small example that reproduces the problem, not hundreds of lines of mostly irrelevant code :-)

Comment: hmmm, yeah, I should've done this example myself! Thank you guys, my problem is elsewhere!